# Mysqli WHERE gives an boolean error

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am trying to get only rows where active = 1 but for some reason it's giving me out this error.

`Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean`

```
$db2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '123');
$imagesQuery = $db2->query("
SELECT
images.id,
images.caption,
images.active,
COUNT(images_likes.id) AS likes

FROM images WHERE active = 1

LEFT JOIN images_likes 
ON images.id = images_likes.image

GROUP BY images.id
");

while($row = $imagesQuery->fetch_object()) {
    $images[] = $row;
} 
echo '<pre style="color: #fff">', print_r($images, true) , '</pre>';
```

Comment: `mysqli::query` will return `false` (boolean value) in case there's an error with the query. Consider adding `printf("Error: %s\n", $db2->error);` right after the query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues

Comment: But what did I do wrong with it? How can I avoid that error?

Comment: You need to write `printf("Error: %s\n", $db2->error);` below the query function in order to find out what's the error.

Comment: The WHERE needs to be after the JOIN, I believe

Comment: Nothing is being outputed only this "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean"

Comment: @andrewsi Nope, I tried that even before posting it here :/

Comment: I don't use mysqli a lot but you could try fetch_assoc() instead fetch_object(). And yes as everybody already  told you WHERE clause go after JOIN clause if that's not a problem now it will be later... GL

Comment: I have switched it to PDO and still the same problem, WHERE is again not working...

Comment: can you create Sql Fiddle with some data so I can test something?

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic Hey I forgot to say that I fixed it. I have called WHERE images.active = 1 instead of active = 1, I realised that the sql was confused because of those two tables...So all along was the solution to select it and call it same as how I selected it. Thanks for the tip about WHERE placement, it helped!

Comment: Great :) I'm glad to hear that you solve it... GL!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
images.id,
images.caption,
images.active,
COUNT(images_likes.id) AS likes

FROM images 

LEFT JOIN images_likes 
ON images.id = images_likes.image
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY images.id
```